# Finding examples of infinite groups where all elements have finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to figure out if there could be an infinite group where all elements had finite order. I gave it a thought and then came up with the group of all integer sequences $\mod n$, which I think can be formally written as $\mathbb{Z}_n^\infty $.

After another moment of thought I realized I didn't like this example, as I just took a finite group and created sequences of elements there.

Are there any other, more satisfying examples? Or is it true that if $G $ satisfies what I am asking, then $G $ is an infinite product of finite groups?

How do these things extend to rings? Defining the product as component-wise I can still think of $\Bbb{Z}_n^\infty$.

Comment: The question at the end is distinct. I'd suggest referencing the question I've just (automatically) linked above, and then turning your final question into the actual question (and changing the title).

Comment: $\mathbb Z/2[x]$ under addition.

Comment: Take a look at the Burnside groups.

Answer (score 5):

How about the group of all roots of unity in $\Bbb C$ under multiplication?
It is Abelian, but is is not a direct product, or direct sum, of finite groups.

Comment: My edit was for a typo. Changed the 3rd last word from "or" to "to".

Comment: Let $G$ be the group of permutations of $\Bbb N$ that fix all but finitely  many members of $\Bbb N.$ Is $G$ isomorphic to a direct product or direct sum of finite groups?